# How to implement overloaded functions using templates in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Suppose I want to define a set of functions, each having 4 overloads, the first overload taking a single parameter of type `int32_t` and the second taking `int64_t`, the third - `uint32_t` and the fourth - `uint64_t`. For each function, all overloads have the same implementation so I could define a function template instead:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T t) {
  // ...
}
```

However this is different from having four overloads because now I have a separate function for each (integer) type that can be used to instantiate `f`. The implementation details of `f` are such that it might not work for other integral types however. To address this I can wrap the function template in four overloaded functions:

```
template <typename T>
void f_impl(T t) {
  // ...
}

void f(int32_t value) { f_impl(value); }
void f(int64_t value) { f_impl(value); }
void f(uint32_t value) { f_impl(value); }
void f(uint64_t value) { f_impl(value); }
```

It works but requires substantial amount of code for each function (4 function overloads + 1 function template). Is there a way to simplify this?

To clarify, it is not desirable to use template directly because it doesn't make sense (for implementation reasons or otherwise) to have its specializations for types other than `int32_t`, `int64_t`, `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`.

---

I've tried using `std::enable_if` already and the problem with it is best illustrated by this example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct is_supported_int {
  static const bool value = false;
};

template <>
struct is_supported_int<int32_t> {
  static const bool value = true;
};

template <>
struct is_supported_int<int64_t> {
  static const bool value = true;
};

// ...

template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_supported_int<T>::value, T>::type>
void f(T t) {
// ...
}

int main() {
  short s = 42;
  f(s);
}
```

Unlike in the original version with overloads which I'm trying to emulate, this example will not compile since `f` will be excluded from the set of matching functions for `short`.

Unfortunately `std::is_integral<T>` as suggested by Rapptz doesn't help either because due to implementation details of `f` this function can only be defined for specific types, not for all integral types.

Comment: I don’t understand why you need the wrappers. The template seems to be enough.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Let's say it doesn't make sense to define f_impl for types other than int32_t, int64_t, uint32_t and uint64_t.

Comment: I don't get it. Each instantiation of the template is an overload of `f`. What more do you need?

Comment: @vitaut Edit the question to include that.

Comment: @vitaut Ah. In those cases use `std::enable_if` to restrict valid template types. I don’t have time now to show how this works but helpfully someone else will write an answer using this.

Comment: @vitaut likewise, I edited my answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: That's a very good point. I thought about using `enable_if` but unfortunately this doesn't play well with integer promotion in this case, for example you can no longer call f with smaller integer type and have a proper overload called.

Comment: @vitaut "substantial amount of code"? Seriously? just 4 wrappers...

Comment: @vitaut What promotion? If you want all integral types supported (because that's what enabling promotion will do), just limit it to all integral types, not just int32/64. And how to do that is in the answers already.

Comment: @rhalbersma: 4 wrappers for 1 function, I need many of these.

Comment: Come one people, if you don't like the question, tell why.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: See the updated question. I do want all integrals supported, but the implementation will not work for types other than int32/int64.

Comment: @vitaut: Your edit changed absolutely nothing. If you want short to be included, then use a trait that includes short. Since you want [u]int32/64 and all types that promote to them, IT'S ALL INTEGRAL TYPES. JUST USE `is_integral`.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Yes it does. You mix implementation and interface. From the user perspective (interface) it should be possible to use any integral type, but from implementation perspective it might be different.

Comment: Then just ask the damn question you want to be answered, i.e., describe exactly what you want (you didn't even say if you want that call with short to use int32 or int64 or uint32 or whatever!). I have a feeling that once you describe what you want accurately the answer will become obvious.

Comment: @vitaut: I have no idea what you're on about. If you really want your own type trait, then just make it use `is_integral` internally. It makes absolutely no difference but there you go.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I am sorry, I am trying to formulate it more exactly to address all the misunderstandings, thus the edits.

Comment: `std::is_integral<T>` isn't implementation defined, it specifically says in the standard that the condition is that it must be an integral type, which under N3376 working draft of the standard section 3.9.1 is defined as both signed and unsigned char, short, int, long, and long long.

Comment: @Rapptz: I am not saying that `std::is_integral<T>` is implementation defined. What I am saying is that the implementation of function `f` only works for specific integer types, otherwise the answer would be obvious - use a single template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would work.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type>
void f(T t) {
    std::cout << "int types only!\n";
}

int main() {
    f(1.234f);
    f(12);
}
```

f(1.234f) would fail to compile but f(12) wouldn't.

Comment: This is very close, but doesn't play well with integer promotions. I'll update my question explaining this in a moment.

Comment: You know what's fantastic about this answer? It solved the updated question even before it was updated!

Comment: This is not 100% equivalent to the original solution with overloads, but probably the closest one can get. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `enable_if` or a static assert to restrict instantiation.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

template<bool X, bool Y>
struct or_ : std::true_type 
{};

template<>
struct or_<false, false> : std::false_type 
{};

template<typename T>
struct valid_type_for_f :
  or_< std::is_same<T, std::uint32_t>::value,
       std::is_same<T, std::uint64_t>::value> // etc.
{};

// static assert
template<typename T>
T f(T t) {
  static_assert(valid_type_for_f<T>::value, "Not a valid type");
  return t;
}

// enable_if
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<valid_type_for_f<T>::value, T>::type
fenable(T t) {
  return t;
}


int main()
{
  float x = 4.2f;
  f(x); // fails
  fenable(x); // fails
  std::uint32_t xx = 23;
  f(xx);
  fenable(xx);
  return 0;
}
```